# Why are the capacitors set up this way in this old tube radio?

Tags: capacitor, rf, radio, vacuum-tube

[image: original schematic]

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with these capacitors, so I can replace them in an old tube radio, but why are they connected in this way?

[image: Schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTNBw4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: L1 should be 24H.  If you read data sheet, they form a filter block to eliminate 60Hz.  They also discuss changes between 25Hz and 60Hz.

Comment: This is a pi-section constant-k or m-derived filter.

Comment: Actually, being a filter for a full wave rectifier, it eliminates 120Hz.

Answer (score 11):

From the schematics it seems some sort of smoothing filter for a full-wave rectifier. At 60Hz the fully-rectified voltage will have a 120Hz frequency and that filter has a notch about at that frequency, as you can see from this LTspice simulation:

[image]

[image]

On the schematics there is also what seems "RECT-80" (to the left of the input of the filter), which may hint at a rectifier (the symbols they use are unknown to me!). It might be a double vacuum diode (wild guess), i.e. a valve with two anodes and one catode which was used to rectify current. The symbol may indicate that the cathode is one with the heating filament of the valve.

**EDIT**

It turns out that there exists an old [rectifier vacuum tube named simply "80"](http://www.r-type.org/exhib/aaa0296.htm).

In that page there is a link to its datasheet, in which you can see this:

[image]

So effectively this confirms my initial guess.

Comment: They forgot to put envelopes on the tubes (no circles around the tube elements).  The Type 80 was a very common full-wave rectifier, with a 5 volt filament which also served as the cathode.

Comment: These old tubes have two digit part numbers. 80 is a full wave rectifier. The angled part is the filament (heater) and also the cathode.  The two adjacent rectangles are the anodes (plates).  It would be a little clearer if they showed the glass envelope (a circle) around the elements (as they did later).

Comment: I was checking out the tubes on this beast the 240 series came out  circa  1929